# Displaying existing content in editable textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to make editable page with javascript and php and I want to display whats already stored in the area however it does not work. Its meant to be a blog page meaning that there are multiple posts. And I am unsure whether the problem is within the js or php.

This is the javascript I am using. The `console.log()` writes that `post_id` is unassigned.

```
$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function () {

         var post_id = $(this).parent().data('id');
         var self = this;

         $.getJSON(settings.server, {post_id: post_id},  function(data){
                var editableText = '<textarea class="editPostBody">' + data.body + '</textarea>';
                console.log(post_id);

                $(".post").parent().replaceWith(editableText);
         });    
});

var formatPost = function(d) {

        var s = '';

  s = '<div class="post" data-id="' + d.post_id + '"><h2 class="postHeading">' + d.title +'</h2>';

  s += d.body;
  s += '<p> Posted on: ' + d.date + '</p>';

  s += '<div class="btn editButton">Edit Post</div>'
  s += '</div>'

        return s;
    };
```

And this is the PHP file
connection to db established prior

```
if(count($_GET)) {

if(isset($_GET['post_id'])){

get_post_id( $_GET['post_id']);

}

}
else{

get_posts();
}


function get_posts() {

global $link;

// $sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM posts";

// $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
// $total = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 5";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}   

// $json = '{"total":"' . $total[0] . '","posts":';
$json = json_encode($rows);
// $json .= "}";

print($json);   
}


function get_post_id($postId){

 global $link;

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = $postId";   
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
 $toSend = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


  print json_encode($toSend);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: There's a few things I noticed, the first being `if(iiset($_GET['post_id'])){` should be `if(isset($_GET['post_id'])){` also why are you using `count()` at the start if you aren't checking whether there's more than X?

Comment: I fixed the typo yet it still does not work. The `count()` is used to determine if there is something in the get array or not

Comment: I decided to add to the question the function that builds the page as I found a mistake in it i had a wrong column name for the id yet after fixing that it still hasnt worked.

Comment: Can't you check what does the php return? Most browsers allow you to do so (by pressing F12 and searching in "network") Then, you could see if the response is what you're searching for

Comment: Well the problem was  `var post_id = $(this).parent().data('post_id');` should have been `var post_id = $(this).parent().data('id');` now the id gets assigned however it does not change the area to text area.

Comment: The PHP is returning following error `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` which is due to the query failing however i dont understand why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code like this

```
function get_post_id($postId){

  global $link;

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id = $postId";  
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  $toSend = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


  print json_encode($toSend);
}
```

and JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function () {

          var post_id = $(this).parent().data('id');
        // console.log(post_id);
          var self = this;

         $.getJSON(settings.server, {post_id: post_id},  function(data){
                var editableText = $('<textarea class="editPostBody">' + data.body + '</textarea>');
            console.log(post_id);
                $(".post").parent().replaceWith(editableText);
         });
```